# Firebase file upload progress jumps from 0 to 100

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using the Firebase Storage to upload files.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress

The upload works well, but the on("state_changed") event is called only twice, so my progress bar jumps from 0% to 100%. Is it possible to get some values between 0 and 100? This would be a better experience for the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of time the `state_changed` event is raised, depends on the size of the file you upload: if fires for each block of 256KB. So if the file is <256KB this is expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you. I uploaded only images :) It works well with larger files

Comment: This is actually pretty bad for many "Image uploading" use cases. It should fire at a limited rate based on the upload target. If I upload a 100KB file it should fire once for each KB. If I upload a 1MB file it should fire once each 10KB. Wouldn't this be better for the user?

Comment: When we upload a 10 MB File ,
 we just get ```50%, 75%, 100%```
This is a very **bad** user experience since the user gets no feedback before```50%``` !
Is there any way to improve this ?

Comment: I believe that is not the case anymore - the first event is reported on 256Kb, but then each event is fired when the amount was doubled, meaning events are fired on: 256Kb, 512Kb, 1024Kb, 2048Kb, 4096Kb and so on (whenever chunk size is increased). @Frank, can you please validate that?